# Can't slide navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

I am doing a project in the android studio, and I need a navigation drawer, I made a navigation but the problem I can't slide it left and right its block without moving.

[slide problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eque8.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="radiofm.arabelradio.MainActivity"
    android:background="#e10716"
    >

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        >

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/id_play"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:background="#e10716"
        android:layout_marginBottom="84dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/arabel"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />




</RelativeLayout>
```

My java code 
I am doing a project in the android studio and I need a navigation drawer, I made a navigation but the problem I can't slide it left and right its block without moving

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    ImageButton id_play;
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    boolean prepared = false;
    boolean started =false;
    String stream ="http://arabelfm.ice.infomaniak.ch/arabelprodcastfm.mp3";






    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        id_play = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.id_play);
        id_play.setEnabled(false);
        //id_play.setText("LOADING");
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        new PlayerTask().execute(stream);
        id_play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (started){
                    started=false;
                    mediaPlayer.pause();
                    id_play.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
                   // id_play.setText("PLAY");
                }
                else {
                    started=true;
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    id_play.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);

                    //id_play.setText("PAUSE");

                }

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: add your java code.

Comment: where is your [DrawerLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html)

Comment: @farhanpatel i edited

Comment: @Kaushik i am begginer can you explain me please 11

Comment: checkout this https://antonioleiva.com/navigation-view/ you will understand how to setup

Comment: @MohamdEl-Saleh check the documentation link I have already provide

Answer (score 2):

```
Just Put your NavigationView bottom of all layout inside DrawerLayout 

Like this 

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="https://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:openDrawer="start">

     ---- Here is your layouts

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
            app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the logic manually:

```
toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please replace RelativeLayout as parent layout to DrawerLayout

```
 <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:openDrawer="start">

        <include
            layout="@layout/app_bar_home_navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>
    ..

    ..
    </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

In MainActivity

```
DrawerLayout drawer;
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle;
 drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
 toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
```

and add This Functionality on menu button click to open and close

```
 if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                    } else {
                        drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                    }
```